# Centering part entries in toc using memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, memoir, parts

I'm using memoir for a large document and want to center the toc entries corresponding to parts (page entries are turned off). I read the manual (specifically pp. 161-166) and while I have no problem adjusting the positions of the part number or title separately, I can't figure out how to center the part number and the title together as a whole. The MWE that demonstrates this is as follows:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\cftpagenumbersoff{part}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\part{Part A}
\chapter{Chapter a}
\end{document}
```

To be more specific, I would like "I Part A" to be horizontally centered. If there were a second part called "B", I would like that to be centered like "II Part B".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, that can be done with much shorter code:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{\hfil\hspace\@tocrmarg #1~}
\makeatother
```

(not entirely sure why though, it's late ...)

Comment: I like that solution but it does not work, where the title of part is longer then one line and you have to have a line break. Then the second line is not centred. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You can redefine the `\@part` command as defined in `memoir.cls`; this command in in charge of producing the part entries in the ToC; the redefinition basically consists in introducing two `\hfil`s to center the entries:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
\makeatletter
\long\def\@part[#1]#2{%
  \M@gettitle{#1}%
  \phantomsection
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\hfil\thepart~#1\hfil}%
    \mempartinfo{\thepart}{#1}{#2}%
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\hfil#1\hfil}%
    \mempartinfo{}{#1}{#2}%
  \fi
  \partmark{#1}%
  {\centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \parskip\z@
   \normalfont
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
     \printpartname \partnamenum \printpartnum
     \midpartskip
   \fi
   \printparttitle{#2}\par}%
  \@endpart}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\part{Part A}
\chapter{Chapter a}
\part{Part B}
\chapter{Chapter b}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The above code will center the entries with respect to the text width minus the length `\@tocrmarg` (default value of `2.55em`) reserved to typeset the page numbers for other sectional units using some extra space; you can change this, and center the entries with respect to the full text width by adding `\hspace*{\@tocrmarg}` just before the first `\hfil`s in my example code above.

Comment: Thanks, but the entries do not appear to be centered with respect to the text block. They appear to be slightly to the left of center.

Comment: @Nut Yes. That's because they are centered having into account the length `\@tocrmarg` (dafault value of `2.55em`) reserved to typeset the page numbers for other sectional units using some extra space; you can change this by adding `\hspace*{2.55em}` just before the first `\hfil`s in my example code above.

Comment: Better still, insert the command `\hspace*{\@tocrmarg}` (instead of `\hspace*{2.55em}`): that way, one needn't even look up the value of this parameter. :-)

Comment: @Mico: right. Added.

Comment: Thanks to Gonzalo and Mico. I selected daleif's answer since it's short and gives proper centering.

Comment: It does not work, where the title of part is longer then one line and you have to have a line break. Then the second line is not centred. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using `memoir` internal macros, I centered parts in ToC with the following code in my preamble :

```
\renewcommand*{\cftpartfont}{\hspace{\@pnumwidth}\hfil} 
\renewcommand*{\cftpartpresnum}{\hspace{\@pnumwidth}}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartafterpnum}{\hfil}
```

It uses `\cftpartfont` and  `\cftpartafterpnum` as hooks and correct for `\@pnumwidth` (width reserved for page numbers) shift.

I also use this to get rid of parts' page numbers :

```
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!