# Centering multiline \part entries in memoir ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, memoir, parts

**Preliminaries:** I have read through the memoir manual section on ToC many times. While I was able to get many things I wanted done, I was not able to fix the last piece.

I also have consulted prior questions/answers (and there are several on trying to get \part entries formatted in various ways, particularly centered) they have not given me an answer. I do not believe this is a duplicate, despite question title similarity. The other questions/answers include:
[Centering part entries in toc using memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36420/centering-part-entries-in-toc-using-memoir),
[How can I properly center my table of contents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323557/how-can-i-properly-center-my-table-of-contents),
[Customize TOC, center align and italics in memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314945/customize-toc-center-align-and-italics-in-memoir),
[How to center part entries in toc with memoir?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210671/how-to-center-part-entries-in-toc-with-memoir), and
[Memoir: Part contents in TOC in two lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478600/memoir-part-contents-in-toc-in-two-lines).

**The issue:** Each part entry should be centered under the ToC heading ("Contents" in bold + italics). I can't get the entries centered.

Each part entry includes the prefix "Part", the part number, a colon, a line break, the title of the part, a space, a centered period, a space, the page number. The word "Part" should be in small caps and the "Part"/space/part number/colon should be in normal font. The part title/centered period/page number should be in boldface. The part title may be multiline. The following image shows the desired end state:
[image]

**The MWE:** This is my current working MWE:

```
\documentclass[smallroyalvopaper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}

\title{\HUGE{\textbf{Name of Book} \\ \LARGE{\textit{Subtitle of book}}}}
\author{\Large{Author's Name}}
\date{Date Written}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\Large\textit{\textbf{Contents}}}

\setpnumwidth{2em}
\setrmarg{4em}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{0em}
\setlength{\cftpartindent}{0em}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{}
\cftsetindents{part}{\cftpartindent}{\@pnumwidth}

\renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{}%
\renewcommand*{\cftpartfont}{\normalsize\scshape}%
\renewcommand*{\cftpartaftersnum}{}%
\renewcommand*{\cftpartaftersnumb}{\\}%

\renewcommand*{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{%
    \cftpartformatpnumhook{#1}%
    \hbox to \@pnumwidth{\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace{\cftpartpagefont #1}\hfil}}%
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}%

\long\def\@part[#1]#2{%
  \M@gettitle{#1}%
  \def\f@rtoc{\hfil\bfseries{#1}}
  \@nameuse{part@f@rtoc@before@write@hook}%
  \phantomsection
  \mempreaddparttotochook
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}%
      {\protect\partnumberline{\hspace*{5em}\hfil Part~\thepart :\hfil\\}\f@rtoc}%
    \mempartinfo{\thepart}{\f@rtoc}{#2}%
  \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\f@rtoc}%
    \mempartinfo{}{\f@rtoc}{#2}%
  \fi
  \mempostaddparttotochook
  \partmark{#1}%
  {\centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \parskip\z@
   \normalfont
   \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
     \printpartname \partnamenum \printpartnum
     \midpartskip
   \fi
   \printparttitle{#2}\par}%
  \@endpart}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\clearpage
\tableofcontents*
\mainmatter
\part{This is the First Part Heading}
\part{This is the Second Part Heading which is a Long Heading to Check for Wrap Formatting}
\part{This is the Third Part Heading}
\end{document}
```

I have tried permutations, iterations, and combinations of the answers in the similar questions. Obviously, none of those have worked: the entries do not center. The current MWE produces the following result:

[image]

(Note: hspace is set at 5em based on one of the other questions. tocrmarg = 4em plus 1em for the gap memoir inserts between number and title.) As a side note, the ToC format I'm trying to achieve was used by Jacques Barzun in his book, *From Dawn to Decadence*. Finally, while there may be places where things could be condensed, if condensing doesn't affect the end result it just "cleans up" the code, I would appreciate it if you would refrain from making those changes. Ultimately, this code is part of a larger project that will be used for pedagogical purposes so being able to walk through line-by-line helps.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Unrelated: note that macros like `\LARGE` does not take arguments. thus after `\LARGE{text}` the size is still `\LARGE`.

Comment: Thanks, @daleif. Been through so many edits I missed the stray {}.

Comment: To clarify, this was a hack for the MWE. In the "real" doc I use a constructed title page.

Comment: I would just have left it out to keep the example as small as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution

There are two parts. First we redefine `\partnumberline` to get rid of the boxing and we'll add a lot of out formatting there. Note that the title part of the toc entry will come as

```
 \partnumberline{number}Title
```

Next we patch `\l@part` to get rid of some grouping.

```
\documentclass[smallroyalvopaper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}

% formatting really does not belong inside \title and friends /daleif
\title{\HUGE{\textbf{Name of Book} \\ \LARGE{\textit{Subtitle of book}}}}
\author{\Large{Author's Name}}
\date{Date Written}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\Large\textit{\textbf{Contents}}}

\setpnumwidth{2em}
\setrmarg{4em}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{0em}
\setlength{\cftpartindent}{0em}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{12pt}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartfont}{}%
% debox \partnumberline
\renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{%
  \centering
  \normalsize\scshape Part~#1:
  \normalfont\bfseries
  \par
}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace#1}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% patch \l@part to remove some grouping

\patchcmd\l@part{%
  {\cftpartfont {#1}}\cftpartfillnum{#2}%
}{%
  #1\cftpartfillnum{#2}%
}{\typeout{patched}}{\FAILED}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\clearpage
\tableofcontents*
\mainmatter
\part{This is the First Part Heading}
\part{This is the Second Part Heading which is a Long Heading to Check for Wrap Formatting}
\part{This is the Third Part Heading}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - this works!

Comment: @kgrady remember to hit the accept mark it it was ok